Struck in Infinite Recomposition due to Horizontal Pager's Pager State
this code snippet do infinite recomposition while scrolling , not able to find why?
How to manage state and animation in a HorizontalPager in Jetpack Compose?
I'm working with Jetpack Compose and trying to create a custom dialog UI that involves a HorizontalPager. I'm using a ComposeView inside my MainActivity to display this UI, but I'm running into issues managing the state, animations, and initial page setup.
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val compose = findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.composeErrorScreen)
        compose.apply {
            visibility = VISIBLE
            setContent {
                val dialogContentState by remember {
                    mutableStateOf(
                        CardsScreenUi(
                            2,  // initialCard
                            listOf(2, 3, 4)  // cardsList
                        )
                    )
                }
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color.Transparent),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomEnd
                ) {
                    DialogContent(dialogContentState)
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }

Here i am adding a composable via JetPack Compose
internal data class CardsScreenUi(
    val initialCard: Int,
    val cardsList: List<Int>
)

@Composable
internal fun BoxScope.DialogContent(
    dialogContentState: CardsScreenUi?,
) {

    Log.d("[Testing]", "Starting ")

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        dialogContentState?.let { data ->
            val (initialCard, cardsList) = data
            val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
                pageCount = {
                    cardsList.size
                }
            )

            val screenWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp
            val pageWidth = remember { 300.dp }
            val sidePadding = remember { (screenWidth - pageWidth) / 2 }

            HorizontalPager(
                state = pagerState,
                pageSpacing = 12.dp,
                pageSize = PageSize.Fixed(pageWidth),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = sidePadding)
            ) { page ->
                // Page content can go here (e.g., display card content)
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(22.dp))

            DotStepper(count = pagerState.pageCount, count2 = pagerState.currentPage)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DotStepper(count: Int, count2: Int) {
    Log.d("[Testing]", "Horizontal Pager  $count and ${count2}")
}


Observation : but when removing dotStepper , then no recomposition happened

Can you please [edit] your question and better describe what the actual issue is that you have? When I execute the above code I only get two log entries: "Starting" and "Horizontal Pager  3 and 0". That seems to be expected. When actually using the pager there will be additional recompositions, but I find nothing unusal about it. Please either make sure the code you provided actually exhibits the problematic behavior or better describe what it is that you find problematic.

I totally agree with @tyg. Neither pageCount nor currentPage should trigger "infinite" recomposition. Especially pageCount that never changes during scrolling. I also checked the sample above and i only get logs only once currentPage changes.

Hello Everyone ,
in initial it will print Starting" and "Horizontal Pager 3 and 0
but as i mentioned above please scroll that black screen , it will print starting infinite times
you have to scroll for see infinite recomposition
i have not create a ui for horizontal pager , you can create for your own for better understanding of the issue. @tyg

@Thracian you can check this also

this code snippet do infinite recomposition while scrolling

I tested your code in a preview also created a layout and tested with MainActivity to check if it can be related to ComposeView but there is no infinite recomposition.

@AkshatSinghal: There is no "black screen" that I could scroll. Only the pager consisting of three elements, and switching between the elements do just a regular amount of recomposition, certainly no infinite recompositions. When you have a "bkack screen", then you apparently haven't tried the code posted here. If you have an issue with other code, then please [edit] the question and provide a [mre] that actually exhibits the problematic behavior.

To prevent unnecessary recompositions, store pagerState.currentPage and pagerState.pageCount in a remember block to observe only the necessary state changes.
val currentPage by remember { derivedStateOf { pagerState.currentPage } }
val pageCount by remember { derivedStateOf { pagerState.pageCount } }

DotStepper(count = pageCount, count2 = currentPage)


can you please give the RCA for it, why does it happen?

how did only passing pagerState.pagecount and pagerState.currentpage as parameter causing infinite recomposition and pagerState changes?
